# null Amount value salesorderdetail on crm 2011-Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to insert data on SalesOrderDetail entity, everything works fine, except for the Amount field which remains null. I don't get any error message.
Here is an example of my code :

```
private void beginCreateSalesOrderDetail()
{
    SalesOrderDetail orderDetail = new SalesOrderDetail();
    orderDetail.SalesOrderId = new EntityReference() 
    { 
       Id = id, 
       LogicalName = "salesorder" 
    };
    orderDetail.Quantity = element.QuantityOnHand;
    orderDetail.ProductId = new EntityReference() 
    { 
        Id = element.ProductId, 
        LogicalName = "product" 
    };
    orderDetail.UoMId = new EntityReference() 
    { 
        Id = new Guid("8DDD2AFB-73CF-E111-8140-00155D55B216"),        
        LogicalName = "uom" 
    };
    orderDetail.TransactionCurrencyId = new EntityReference() 
    { 
        Id = new Guid("77D695B5-ACB4-E111-97BC-00155D55B216"), 
        LogicalName = "transactioncurrency" 
    };

    Money Taxe = new Money(); 
    Money Amount = new Money();
    Taxe.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(element.totalCharges);
    Amount.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(InvoiceTotal);
    orderDetail.Tax = Taxe;
    orderDetail.BaseAmount = Amount;
    orderDetail.PricePerUnit = element.Price;
    orderDetail.Description = element.PDesc;
   _context.AddToSalesOrderDetailSet(orderDetail);
 _context.BeginSaveChanges(EndCreateSalesOrderDetail, orderDetail);

}



private void EndCreateSalesOrderDetail(IAsyncResult result)
  {

     try
     {
       _context.EndSaveChanges(result);
     }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

   }
```

Please note that only the amount which remains null

Comment: is amount a Currency value what is it defined as in the Database..?

Comment: Yes, Amount is a Currency Value.

Comment: why don't you wrap that code around a try{}catch and see if you get an error perhaps the error is being suppressed

Comment: Have you also stepped thru the code using the debugger..?

Comment: Of course, without any error message,

Comment: The Amount value  comes from CRM system calculation ??

Comment: Wben can you post what values you are getting up until the line where you are trying to get Amount.. for example what is the Value of Taxe are you missing code also in that post.. where is the .Save() method..?

Comment: using debugger, I have 150 $ in the amount value, 10 $ in the taxe

Comment: Is there a restrictions on Crm calculating ??

Comment: I just tested this code using the value of 150 and the string formats the value to `$150.00` `            CultureInfo current = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            decimal myMoney = 150m;

            //formats as money in current culture, like $99.99
            string formattedMoney = myMoney.ToString("C", current);`

Comment: If you were to take just this line of code `CultureInfo current = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;` what is the value of `current` I think that this may the issue but not really sure. I need to know the exact value thanks

Comment: my Amount variable is a Money type, Money Amount = new Money(), I Then set the value that I have in it, like Amount.value = Convert.toDecimal(150); orderDetail.BaseAmount = Amount; the value of current is "en-CA"

Comment: after you run the Amount.Value = Convert.toDecemal(150); what value do you have for Amount.value..? also please put some code in  your Catch block.. what is the value of Amount in the Database decimal and Currency are not the same fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the solution.
Actually, there is a restrictions in crm 2011 to calcul the amounts of products,
We have to create a Price List, and associate each product in the list.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is because of Unit field mismatch between Price List Item and Quote Detail.